# How to debug Firefox CPU Usage

Tags: firefox, javascript, cpu-usage

I'm seeking advice where to look for possible causes of the following situation:

The CPU usage of my favorite JavaScript browser game (https://grepolis.com) is too high when idle. When no input is made, there is literally no animation visible (only some numbers changing every some seconds).

The built in web developer tools (Shift-F5), display a sequence of `requestAnimationFrame` and `Recalculate Style`, repeated once per frame (60 fps). Both calls show a CPU usage of less than 0.1 ms each in most occurrences. That makes about ten milliseconds per second, or 1 % CPU usage. There is no network activity for more than a minute.

But the real CPU usage visible in task manager or process explorer is about 75 % of a CPU core (44 seconds of additional CPU time used in one minute). There is no plugin container loaded - the activity is in the main Firefox process (no flash or other plugin). According to process explorer, the active thread has a start address in `firefox.exe!GetHandleVerifier` googling of which dit not yield some explanation. The call stacks displayed in process explorer for this thread look very different each time so I did not recognize similarities.

When changing to another browser tab and minimizing the Firefox window, the CPU usage reduces to 14 % of a CPU core (8 s CPU time per minute), so I'm convinced the CPU usage is caused by the several megabytes of JavaScript code of that game which is way too large to read.

**How can I find the root cause for my CPU usage, i.e. find the component responsible for the CPU usage ?**

The issue is independent of browser version (same behavior since years) and worsens with run time. A page reload relaxes the situation, but does not solve it (CPU usage still high despite the application being idle). There is enough memory available and I'm using the 64-bit version, but found no difference to the 32-bit version. Win 7 Professional. I did not check other operating systems or browsers.

This game is the only website where I have unclear CPU usage: All other websites I use consume CPU only when active.